# jhipster microservices one andpoint for all microservices

Tags: jhipster, api-gateway

i want to use one single path from api gateway for all microservices it is possible?.
i have:

http://microservice1:8081/api/user
http://microservice2:8082/api/user2

i want all services called in gateway as

http://gateway:8080/api/microservice1/api/user
http://gateway:8080/api/microservice2/api/user2

Comment: i try to set zuul prefix in gateway application but not work

Comment: Did you try to add `zuul.stripPrefix=false`as well ?